Missing space in first names, will there be an issue?
I booked flight from travel website giving correct first names as per passport but when I try to check the ticket from the airline they are missing space on between firstname and middle name.
Passport Firstnames:   Firstname MiddleName
Lastname: Lastname
Ticket name showing as : Firstnamemiddlename Lastname

This is normal due to the design of the airlines booking system.
